# How to change array in my quiz so that the next question comes up with correct button values/words

Tags: vb.net

For my final coding project. I need my code so that when i press a button to answer a question, the code brings up another question stored in my array and i coded it so that each question comes with its own words for each button

```
If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(0) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(0)
        Button2.Text = "41-3"
        Button3.Text = "7-0"
        Button4.Text = "27-2"

 ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(1) Then
        Button1.Text = "Pink"
        Button2.Text = "Grey"
        Button3.Text = Form1.answers(1)
        Button4.Text = "White"

ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(x) Then "etc etc etc"
```

Right now when I press the button the question changes but the buttons remain the same from the first question of the quiz I used this sub in each of the 4 button click's private subs to do it.

```
Sub ChangeQuestion()
    Form1.x = (Form1.rn.Next(0, 19))
    RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(Form1.x)
End Sub
```

My Entire Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Public StudentName As String
Public questions(19) As String
Public answers(19) As String
Public x As Integer
Public rn As New Random

Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Questions
    questions(0) = "What is the biggest win in soccer"
    questions(1) = "What colour is Real Madrid's 2017-2018 season away kit"
    questions(2) = "Neymar Plays for PSG" 'T/F
    questions(3) = "What year did Manchester United sign Robin Van Persie"
    questions(4) = "Neymar is number 10 in Brazil" 'T/F
    questions(5) = "How much money do Manchester United have to pay for their 2014-15 kits?"
    questions(6) = "What club loaned David Beckham twice?"
    questions(7) = "Julio Cesar is a Center Back" 'T/F
    questions(8) = "How many clubs did Zlatan Ibrihimovic play for by 2014"
    questions(9) = "Agger is Liverpool's star defender" 'T/F
    questions(10) = "What is the purpose of trapping the ball"
    questions(11) = "Which of the following are not tackling variations"
    questions(12) = "Each team may have __ players including a goalie"
    questions(13) = " To shoot the ball, players should point their toes to the ground and kick the ball with the laces"
    questions(14) = "If an offensive player is fouled in the box, the result is?"
    questions(15) = "A player is allowed to kick, trip, jump at, charge, strike, push, hold or spit at an opponent" 'T/F
    questions(16) = "it is best to pass with which part of the foot?"
    questions(17) = "A penalty kick is taken __ yards away from the goal line"

    questions(18) = "What basic soccer skill is used when the ball goes out of bounds on the sideline?"
    questions(19) = "Can every player use their hands?" 'T/F


    'Answers
    answers(0) = "31-0"
    answers(1) = "Black"
    answers(2) = "True"
    answers(3) = "2012"
    answers(4) = "True"
    answers(5) = "75 Million"
    answers(6) = "AC Milan"
    answers(7) = "False"
    answers(8) = "6"
    answers(9) = "False"
    answers(10) = "To absorb the energy of the ball and control it"
    answers(11) = "Forearm tackle "
    answers(12) = "11"
    answers(13) = "True"
    answers(14) = "Penalty"
    answers(15) = "False"
    answers(16) = "Inside"
    answers(17) = "12"
    answers(18) = "Throw In"
    answers(19) = "False"
    txtName.Text = StudentName

End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    x = (rn.Next(0, 19))
    Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = questions(x)
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(0) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(0)
        Button2.Text = "41-3"
        Button3.Text = "7-0"
        Button4.Text = "27-2"



    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(1) Then
        Button1.Text = "Pink"
        Button2.Text = "Grey"
        Button3.Text = Form1.answers(1)
        Button4.Text = "White"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(2) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(2)
        Button2.Text = "False"
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(3) Then
        Button1.Text = "2009"
        Button2.Text = "2010"
        Button3.Text = "2011"
        Button4.Text = Form1.answers(3)


    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(4) Then
        Button1.Text = "False"
        Button2.Text = Form1.answers(4)
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(5) Then
        Button1.Text = "73 Million"
        Button2.Text = "74 Million"
        Button3.Text = Form1.answers(5)
        Button4.Text = "76 Million"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(6) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(6)
        Button2.Text = "Liverpool"
        Button3.Text = "Arsenal"
        Button4.Text = "England"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(7) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(7)
        Button2.Text = "True"
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(8) Then
        Button1.Text = "3"
        Button2.Text = "4"
        Button3.Text = "5"
        Button4.Text = Form1.answers(8)

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(9) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(9)
        Button2.Text = "True"
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(10) Then
        Button1.Text = "To stop the ball"
        Button2.Text = "To prepare for a throw-in"
        Button3.Text = Form1.answers(10)
        Button4.Text = "To hide the ball"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(11) Then
        Button1.Text = "Block tackle"
        Button2.Text = Form1.answers(11)
        Button3.Text = "Slide tackle"
        Button4.Text = "Poke tackle"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(12) Then
        Button1.Text = "9"
        Button2.Text = "12"
        Button3.Text = "10"
        Button4.Text = Form1.answers(12)

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(13) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(13)
        Button2.Text = "False"
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(14) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(14)
        Button2.Text = "Free-Kick"
        Button3.Text = "Throw in"
        Button4.Text = "Go"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(15) Then
        Button1.Text = "True"
        Button2.Text = Form1.answers(15)
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(16) Then
        Button1.Text = "Toes"
        Button2.Text = "Outside"
        Button3.Text = Form1.answers(16)
        Button4.Text = "Heel"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(17) Then
        Button1.Text = "13"
        Button2.Text = "15"
        Button3.Text = "11"
        Button4.Text = Form1.answers(17)

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(18) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(18)
        Button2.Text = "Free Kick"
        Button3.Text = "Goal Kick"
        Button4.Text = "Penalty"

    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(19) Then
        Button1.Text = Form1.answers(19)
        Button2.Text = "True"
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Bruh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bruh.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    ChangeQuestion()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ChangeQuestion()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ChangeQuestion()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ChangeQuestion()
End Sub

Sub ChangeQuestion()
    Form1.x = (Form1.rn.Next(0, 19))
    RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(Form1.x)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to read the documentation very closely. A detail that you missed on the `Random.Next` method is that the first argument in included but the second argument is excluded. This means that rn.Next(0, 19) will include the 0 index but element 19 will never be selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488217/vbnet-quiz-how-can-i-make-my-quiz-go-to-next-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting up the answers in Form2.Load You need to move that code to a separate Sub and then call it from the Form2.Load and each of the answer buttons.

```
Private Sub FillAnswers()
        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(0) Then
            Button1.Text = Form1.answers(0)
            Button2.Text = "41-3"
            Button3.Text = "7-0"
            Button4.Text = "27-2"

        ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(1) Then
            Button1.Text = "Pink"
            Button2.Text = "Grey"
            Button3.Text = Form1.answers(1)
            Button4.Text = "White"
       'etc...
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillAnswers()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        FillAnswers()
End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        FillAnswers()
End Sub

'etc...
```

Although this should answer your question you have a few other problems to think about.

1. How to keep score
2. How to prevent duplicate questions.

Comment: Sweet works well, i feel like i might be asking for too much but do you have a broad idea on the code required to solve the 2 problems you listed? @Mary

Comment: There are many ways to do the 2 things I mentioned. Some would require a redesign of the program. You have missed the overall planning stage of programming. It can be hard to retrofit requirements to existing code but this is a good lesson to learn the necessity of planning.

Comment: As to keeping score. You could add "correct" to the tag property and then check the tag of the button clicked. If the tag reads "correct" increment a Form level variable. Be sure to clear the tab property before going to the next question.

Comment: As to the duplicate questions, I think it gets complicated with you current design. You will have to keep a list of indexes selected then have a function that returns true when the new selected index is not in the list. Use a do ...while not function with your rnd.Next inside .